# Names for ATA and SATA disks in Linux

Tags: linux, hard-disk, sata, pata

Assume that we have two disks, one master SATA and one master ATA. How will they show up in /dev?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Depending on your SATA driver and your distribution's configuration, they might show up as `/dev/hda` and `/dev/hdb`, or `/dev/hda` and `/dev/sda`, or `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`. Distributions and drivers are moving towards having everything hard disk called `sd?`, but PATA drivers traditionally used `hd?` and a few SATA drivers also did.

The device names are determined by the `udev` configuration. For example, on Ubuntu 10.04, the following lines from `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules` make all ATA hard disks appear as `/dev/sd*` and all ATA CD drives appear as `/dev/sr*`:

```
# ATA devices with their own "ata" kernel subsystem
KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}!="?*", SUBSYSTEMS=="ata", IMPORT{program}="ata_id --export $tempnode"
# ATA devices using the "scsi" subsystem
KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}!="?*", SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", ATTRS{vendor}=="ATA", IMPORT{program}="ata_id --export $tempnode"
```

Comment: The first part of this answer is correct, but the second part is not. The `==` operator *compares* the `KERNEL` name with `sd*`, it doesn't *set* it.

Answer (score 4):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, the first parallel ATA hard drive under Linux will be `/dev/hda`, the second will be `/dev/hdb`, followed by `/dev/hdc`, etc.

*Serial* ATA devides will show up the same way SCSI and USB devices do: `/dev/sda` will be the first one, followed by `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc/`, etc.

Comment: I don't think this is true any more. At least with recent Fedora release, parallel ATA disks get /dev/sda etc too.

Comment: This is how it is on my Ubuntu machine, but I'm not bleeding edge, so maybe it's different.

Answer (score 3):

- SATA - `/dev/sdX`
- SSD -  `/dev/sdX`
- SCSCi - `/dev/sdX`
- IDE - `/dev/hda`

Any drive which start with S (sata,ssd,scsci)  is sda and IDE is hda

Comment: Simple but is this precise?

Comment: @firo, it isn't universal. It is determined by *userland* configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Other answers discuss SATA, IDE, SCSI, etc, but I thought I'd add the new NVMe. In modern kernels, NVMe drives use `/dev/nvmeXnY` for a drive, and `/dev/nvmeXnYpZ` for partitions. For example, partition 5 on NVMe drive (0, 1) would be `/dev/nvme0n1p5`. The block devices behave just like the `hdX` and `sdX` drives.

Essentially, parrallel connections use `hdX` and serial connections use `sdX`, and NVMe, the oddball, uses `nvmeXnY`